# Examine which row/function in R code takes the most time within function?

Tags: r, profiling, performance-testing

I have a set of functions that run within a wrapper:

```
wrapper_func <- function(x,y,z,.....) {

t <- foo1(x,y)
kuku <- foo2(t,z)
....
final_res <- foo20(t, kuku, ...)

return(final_res)

}
```

It runs slowly and I want to understand who is the bottleneck/troublemaker.
Please advise which function can perform deeper analysis (benchmark?microbenchmark?...) that will show the drilldown - which row/function takes the most time/resources?

I have found out another [option](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

and go to the Memory profiling with lineprof chapter.

What do you think?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would assume they didn't like that your example was not reproducible, or thought it was easy to find a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Rprof` to profile your R code and find the performance bottlenecks; here's a short example

```
tmp <- tempfile()
Rprof(tmp)
example(glm)
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)
```

A more extensive description can be found at [this R-bloggers article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/profiling-r-code/).

Comment: @steves I don't know why your question was downvoted. However, please note that asking people to upvote your question is considered rude on SO and might very well backfire (i.e. result in more downvotes). Protecting a question will not prevent downvotes (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions); also, protecting questions is reserved for very high-traffic questions since these tend to attract lots of unusable answers. Your question clearly falls not into that category.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the `microbenchmark` outcomes to see your performance bottlenecks:

```
library(microbenchmark)

wrapper_func <- function(x,y,z,.....) {

  t <- foo1(x,y)
  print(microbenchmark(foo1(x,y)))
  kuku <- foo2(t,z)
  print(microbenchmark(foo2(t,z)))
  ....
  final_res <- foo20(t, kuku, ...)
  print(microbenchmark(foo20(t, kuku, ...)))

  return(final_res)

}
```